# What do you call someone who is always wrong?

Tags: single-word-requests

So I'm doing readworks questions in class I have have to give a character trait but I don't know what you call someone that is always wrong.....

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a word. Can anyone always be wrong in everything? Or are you looking more for a kind of nickname, e.g. Mr Wrong or as an adjective: the ever-erring Mr X.

Comment: Can you give a sentence with a blank to show how you think you want this word to be used?

Comment: Ask my teen-age daughter: she will say it's me...

Comment: What Mitch said, plus, look in a thesaurus and tell us where your search for the right word broke down. // Do you mean like when someone carries a cloud above his head in a comic strip, everywhere he goes?

Answer (score 1):

If such a person is *reliably* always wrong, you may call them a **contra-indicator**. This is sometimes used in financial markets. You may not know what to do, but then you look at what the contra-indicator does, and you do the opposite for virtually guaranteed success.

Examples:

https://realmoney.thestreet.com/articles/06/10/2016/cramer-ultimate-oil-contra-indicator-has-spoken

https://www.guggenheiminvestments.com/perspectives/global-cio-outlook/davos-as-contra-indicator

https://finance-market-news.com/tag/goldman-contraindicator/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is anything that describes someone who is ALWAYS wrong.

But someone who has a tendency always to be wrong, or show bad judgment, is sometimes described as ***wrong-headed***.

Answer (score 0):

There is no word for someone who is always wrong but im sure we can come up with few suggestions
here is my suggestion

1. Naive - adjective (of a person or action) showing a lack of experience, wisdom, or judgement

Answer (score 0):

[Unsound](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=unsound&submit.x=23&submit.y=15) (*adj.*) feels like it might work.

> 1. Not dependably strong or solid.
> 2. Not physically or mentally healthy.
> 3. Not true or logically valid; fallacious: an unsound conclusion.

Depending on the context, I'd feel confident in the wrongness of someone described as unsound.